# how to configure express js application according to environment? like development, staging and production?

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

I am new to expressjs app development, now need to configure application as per environment. came across 'node-env-file' , 'cross-env'. but hardly understood anything. Pls suggest how to set env variables as per environment or some good documentation suggestions pls?
Based on environment, I would like to load my configuraiton file.As of now, I have two config files, one for dev and one for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to set `NODE_ENV` as the environmental variable to determine whether the given environment is `production` or `staging` or `development`. The code base will run based on this set variable.

The variable needs to set in `.bash_profile`

```
$ echo export NODE_ENV=production >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

For more, check [Running Express.js in Production Mode](https://www.hacksparrow.com/running-express-js-in-production-mode.html)

I follow [Ghost.org](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost) (a Node.js production)  app's model.

- Setting [environments](http://support.ghost.org/config/#about-environments)

Once that is done, you can have the environmental details in respective json files like `config.production.json`, `config.development.json`

Next, you need to load one of these file based on the environment.

```
var  env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var Nconf = require('nconf'),
nconf = new Nconf.Provider(),
nconf.file('ghost3', __dirname + '/env/config.' + env + '.json');
```

For more on how Ghost does this, check [config/index.js](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/server/config/index.js)

Comment: oh yes, It helped me. Sorry for replying late.

Answer (score 0):

I use a **.env** file with env vars:

```
VAR=VALUE
```

And read that with `source` command before running express

```
$ source .env
$ node app.js
```

Then, to access inside express, you can use:

```
var temp = process.env.VAR; //contains VALUE
```

You can use **dotenv** module, to automatically load .env file